# IIS 8 - Allow specific URL to be browsed from localhost only

Tags: iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

Windows Server 2012 R2 running IIS 8.

Is it possible to allow a specific URL to be viewed from localhost and deny access from any remote browser?

**UPDATE:**

With "specific URL" i mean a specific file or resource, like a .php file to be executed only locally.

Comment: in windows firewall block port 80 , 443, or add a iis firewall rule to only allow 127.0.0.1 and or the servers internal ip

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With "specific URL" i mean a specific file or resource, like a .php file to be executed only locally.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <fileExtensions applyToWebDAV="false">
                 <add fileExtension=".php" allowed="false" />
            </fileExtensions>
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
  </configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This request filter denies access to all php files listed into a directory, what if i want to deny access to a specific file only?

Comment: try  url re write https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: I don't think url rewriting suites my needs. I tried with the access block rule but it blocks access from localhost too.

Comment: Solved adding a Request Blocking Rule and selecting "Block access based on IP Address". Thank you!